# get Web view notification when load a video

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

> I want to get webview notifications when its fired or when we load a
>   video on web view then we get all webview related notifications
>
> or    I want to get  specific application notifications before exiting
>   an application. How can I do that ?